# Preferences Xamarin.Essentials - First time check if empty?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I am working with Xamarin.Forms and I am trying to check if the preferences is empty or null after launching the app. Something like this

```
InitializeComponent();
if (Preferences.ismpty || Preferences == null)
{
MainPage = new GamerTagPage();
}
else
{
MainPage = new HomePage();
}
```

Comment: You can merge them in one method call string.IsNullOrEmpty(), but what is the question exactly ?

Comment: I don't think Preferences is ever null.  You can check for the existence of a specific key.  Or if you want to know if this is the first run of your app, you can use Essentials Versions to do that

Comment: @Cfun how to check if there is a value for a specific key or if it's empty or null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var IsExist = Preferences.ContainsKey("YourKey")
```

to know if `YourKey` exists or no, and for the value you can check it with:

```
string returnedValue = Preferences.Get("YourKey", string.Empty)
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnedValue))
   MainPage = new GamerTagPage();
else
   MainPage = new HomePage();
```

Answer (score 2):

Im using:

```
 if (Preferences.ContainsKey("YourKey") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get("YourKey", string.Empty)))
{
   //Your code if exist
}
else
{
   //Your code if not exist
}
```

That should work in the most reasons.